# How to change physical layout of the keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I bought my Mac in Spain. I cannot find change keyboard type in Keyboard preferences. I have set to English language but many keys are physically different.

How do I change the physical layout of the keyboard to standard British keyboard?

Comment: You want to change the actual physical buttons? Why didn't you just buy your Mac in the UK then? lol. Also I guess you can pull them off and replace them with english mac keys, but ermm... may not work well.

Comment: This may help: http://www.dotkam.com/2011/01/04/edit-keyboard-layout-on-mac/

Comment: Thanks Dan. Will try Ukelete. I bought the Mac in Spain because I have a home here.

Comment: Ah fair enough. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

OS X includes an British keyboard layout that you can switch to under `Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources`. If you hit the `+` button and search for `British` it'll come up. That'll give you Apple's version of a British keyboard layout.

If you'd like British to match a PC's keyboard, there's a second Apple mapping named `British - PC`.  This'll put the `@` and `|` symbols where they should be in that layout.

You might find that Apple's `British - PC` keyboard mapping isn't quite right, as because their British keyboards aren't laid out as a typical British ([BS4822](http://blogs.transparent.com/english/differences-between-the-us-and-uk-computer-keyboard/)) keyboard is. There's a great solution for this with a [custom keyboard mapping](http://liyang.hu/osx-british.xhtml). The one I linked there works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the UK-English keyboard layout get some [replacement stickers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005DPTUS0) and stick them carefully on your Spanish keyboard.